# asp.net add link button dynamically click function

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to add a LinkButton dynamically

This is the html code:

```
         <div id="resultDivText" runat="server">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>
```

This is the c# code

```
            LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
            lb.Text = songName + "</br>"; //LinkButton Text
            lb.ID = song.Key.ToString(); // LinkButton ID’s
            lb.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(song.Key); 
            lb.CommandName = Convert.ToString(song.Key); 
            lb.Click += new EventHandler(test_Click);                      
            this.form1.Controls.Add(lb);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb);
```

And this is the "test_Click" function

```
    protected void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showAllSong("let it be");
    }
```

When i run the code it's show me the linkButton list but when i click on it nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code ..

```
    static bool enable = false;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DynamicButton();
        }
        else if (enable)
        {
            DynamicButton();
        }
    }
    protected void btnBindMapping_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        enable = true;
        DynamicButton();
    }
    protected void DynamicButton()
    {
        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
        lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.Text = songName + "</br>"; //LinkButton Text
        lb.ID = song.Key.ToString(); // LinkButton ID’s
        lb.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(song.Key);
        lb.CommandName = Convert.ToString(song.Key);
        lb.Click += new EventHandler(test_Click);
        this.form1.Controls.Add(lb);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb);
    }
    protected void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('done'); </script>");
    }
```

Comment: ok
when call the DynamicButton function i send also a Dictionary 
when i put the Dictionary static it solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You code is fine ..it works as expected ..But change this line

```
this.form1.Controls.Add(lb);
```

to

```
this.Controls.Add(lb);
```

Note:It postback to your server not a client sided event

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` in the LinkButton, you have to delegate a `Command` not a `Click`.

```
lb.Command += new CommandEventHandler(test_Click);

protected void test_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(e.CommandArgument + "<br>" + e.CommandName);
}
```

And remove the line `this.form1.Controls.Add(lb);`

And this is not clear from your question, but you have to create that button every time the page is loaded, and that includes a PostBack.

Answer (score 0):

In give detail you have not mention. when this dynamic button is created.

Because that may create a issue.

If you call your c# code in page load event then it works.

```
        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
        lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.Text = songName + "</br>"; //LinkButton Text
        lb.ID = song.Key.ToString(); // LinkButton ID’s
        lb.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(song.Key); 
        lb.CommandName = Convert.ToString(song.Key); 
        lb.Click += new EventHandler(test_Click);                      
        this.form1.Controls.Add(lb);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb);
```

if  that button create dynamically on oninit or onload event then it works.

Comment: i'm actually create this linkButton on a OnClick event

Comment: You are creating linkbutton dynamically and it is adding when you click on any button, but when you click on you dyanmically create button . It fire a postback event and after postback it deleteing the control from the page. So, you must add the control in "page_load" again